# FabricClient.TestManagementClient.StartPartitionRestartAsync throws COMException on ubuntu

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

I have a console app which restarts a servicefabric service . I am using System.Fabric.FabricClient to restart any service fabric service. This console app works fine when published as win-x64 to restart  servicefabric services deployed on windows cluster but the same application fails when published as linux-x64 on ubuntu VM to restart servicefabric services on ubuntu cluster.
The console application is published as windows-x64 for windows cluster and linux-x64 for ubuntu VM. This is the method in console app.

```
        public async Task TestRestart()
    {
        var _tenantAppUri = new Uri($"fabric:/servicename");
        var fabricClient = new FabricClient();
        var restartOperation = Guid.NewGuid();
        await fabricClient.TestManager.StartPartitionRestartAsync(restartOperation, PartitionSelector.PartitionKeyOf(_tenantAppUri, 1), RestartPartitionMode.AllReplicasOrInstances);
    }
```

The error is:

```
System.Fabric.FabricException : An error occurred during this operation.  Please check the trace logs for more details.
----> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException : Error 7434 (0x80071D0A)
```

The console app is executed from the ubuntu VM. Any reason for this error and any fix ?

Comment: COM is a Windows specific technology

Comment: Does FabricClient  works only for windows ?